# Update Spring Data create a new record in case of invalid primary key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jhipster

I am using Spring Data in my application and call **"save"** Repository method to **insert** a new record or **update** an existing entity if I pass an **ID (Primary key)**.

But I notice that when I passed an **ID** which it does not exist on my database a new record inserted, how I can prevent this behaviour?

I need to throw an exception in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of **save** method is as follows:

```
@Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

So it checks as is it new or not. If it is new, it persists else it merge.
In this case you can use `CrudRepository.existsById(Integer id)`  method to check whether it exists or not and accordingly you can throw exception as follows :

Ex:

```
   public void updatePost(Post post) {
        if(!repo.existsById(post.getPostId())){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Resource with given id"+post.getPostId()+" not exists");
        }
        repo.save(post);
    }
```